# C++ XML-RPC Calling

Tags: c++, pandorabots

I haven't seen any documentation for calling XML-RPC by inputing certain strings and get respone of some strings in c++ by connecting to an XML API. This is a documentation provided by the server. I can't figure out how to do this

```
    A client can interact with a Pandorabot by POST'ing to:

    http://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk-xml
    The form variables the client needs to POST are:

    botid - see H.1 above.
    input - what you want said to the bot.
    custid - an ID to track the conversation with a particular customer. This variable is optional. If you don't send a value Pandorabots will return a custid attribute value in the <result> element of the returned XML. Use this in subsequent POST's to continue a conversation.
    This will give a text/xml response. For example:

    <result status="0" botid="c49b63239e34d1d5" custid="d2228e2eee12d255">
      <input>hello</input>
      <that>Hi there!</that>
    </result>

    The <input> and <that> elements are named after the corresponding AIML elements for bot 
input and last response.
 If there is an error, status will be non-zero and there will be a human readable <message> element included describing the error. 

For example:
    <result status="1" custid="d2228e2eee12d255">
      <input>hello</input>
      <message>Missing botid</message>
    </result>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the actual [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) protocol to me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to communicate via HTTP in C++ is to use a library designed for that purpose. For example, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) provides all the facilities you would need to send and receive the kind of requests and responses you showed in the question.

Comment: cURL for c++ doesn't provide any documentation, Can you please tell how to do this?

Comment: All the libcurl documentation can be found on the [API](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) page. You'll be using the C interface (which can also be used in C++). Use the "Easy interface" as documented there.

Comment: I coudn't see how to set strings (for variables like botid custid) and request a respone